# How to send success and error messages to jQuery AJAX call from a webmethod

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, webmethod

I am calling an asp.net webform's webmethod using jQuery AJAX, from an aspx page. When the webmethod experiences an exception I am throwing an HttpResponseException exception. I am not sure what's the best way to return a success message. In a Web API, I would have returned a ApiController.Created(HttpStatusCode) or Ok(200). But I don't see such an option available on a webmethod. In the AJAX call I have to handle success and error accordingly. The following is my code:

```
[WebMethod()]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ProcessData(CustomerData customerData)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsync(<data>);

            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return ???;//how to send success message?
            }
            else
            {
                string reasonAndStatusCode = resp.StatusCode + "; " + resp.ReasonPhrase;
                string errorMessage = "Method Name: ProcessData." +
                                      "Did not process customer data." +
                                      "Status Code and Reason: " +
                                      reasonAndStatusCode;
                HttpResponseMessage error = GenerateError(resp.StatusCode, errorMessage.ToString());
                throw new HttpResponseException(error);
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               

            HttpResponseMessage error = GenerateError(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                errorMessage.ToString());

            throw new HttpResponseException(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you can only return a string, so change the return type of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the response status code using HttpContext Current static object.

For example, if you want to send a 404 status code, see the code below.

```cs
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
```